# SPRING redirect handling in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring, redirect, post

I am trying to redirect pageOne.html to pageTwo.html, based on the response of a POST call made to SPRING REST API. Both these pages are static pages.

The request is made from angular js:

```
$http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'/now/plan/GetPlanByBasicContext/',
        data: JSON.stringify(form.data),
        headers: 
        {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

    })
    .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(header('Location'));
        $window.location.href = header('Location');
     })
    .error(function(data, status) {
        console.log((data || 'Req Failed') + ': ' + status);
    });
```

Above request is made to the following SPRING POST API,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetPlanByBasicContext/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getPlanByBasicContext() 
{
  return "redirect:/resource/pageTwo.html";
}
```

In angular JS controller, I get `data` with the html content of the page homeTwo.html and `header` without any `location` attribute which I can use with angular JS.

When I make this call from fiddler, I get `location` attribute in header with http status as,
`HTTP/1.1 302 Found`

Is there any way to achieve SPRING redirection with angular JS?